# How to make this type of graphs used to talk about regular rooted trees?

Tags: tikz-trees, graphs, tikz-qtree

I have been checking different posts but I still do not fully comprehend how to make these types of graphs:

[image]

I am also trying to draw these pictures, but I am not sure what tool I should use for this. Is the first time I try to do this in LateX so  don't even know  the name of these types of graphs:

[image]

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. The first image is a very simple tree that I would recommend using `forest` for. There are lots of simple `forest` examples to work from on the site. The only part that might pose some issues is the placement of the annotations. So edit your question to show what you've tried and we can help you with the parts you don't understand.  The second image is a completely different question and should be asked separately. But in both cases you really should show a small document that shows what you've tried.

Comment: I suggest using `tikz` . You find a neat short introduction and all details in the bigger manual here: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf . // You may want to see some examples from here: https://texample.net/tikz/examples/feature/trees/ or here https://texample.net/tikz/examples/feature/forest/ .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first figure, I suggest using `forest`. Use `name=` to name the nodes. Then you can use ordinary `tikz` commands at the end.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\tikzset{mytext/.style={font=\tiny, text=teal}}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
for tree={circle, fill=teal, inner sep=1pt, outer sep=0pt, s sep=5mm}
[
  [, label={[mytext]180:{1}}[,name=a1][,name=a2][,name=a3]]
  [, name=n2, label={[mytext]180:{2}}[,name=b1][,name=b2][,name=b3]]
  [, name=n3, label={[mytext]180:{$d$}}[,name=c1][,name=c2][,name=c3]]
]
\path(n2)--node{$\cdots$}(n3);
\path(a2)--node{$\scriptstyle\cdots$}(a3);
\path(b2)--node{$\scriptstyle\cdots$}(b3);
\path(c2)--node{$\scriptstyle\cdots$}(c3);
\draw[decorate, teal, decoration={brace, mirror, raise=3pt}](a1.south west)--node[yshift=-2ex, mytext]{$d$}(a3.south east);
\draw[decorate, teal, decoration={brace, mirror, raise=3pt}](b1.south west)--node[yshift=-2ex, mytext]{$d$}(b3.south east);
\draw[decorate, teal, decoration={brace, mirror, raise=3pt}](c1.south west)--node[yshift=-2ex, mytext]{$d$}(c3.south east);
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. But there is a small problem I don't understand: 
The script only works if I write:
for tree={circle, fill=teal, inner sep=1pt, outer sep=0pt, s sep=5mm}
Instead of:
for tree={circle, fill=teal, inner sep=1pt, outer sep=0pt, s sep=5mm, if sibling=l{f}{}}

Do you know what is the problem with "if sibling=l{f}{}" and what does it do?

Comment: @Gillyweeds: Sorry about that. I was adjusting the spacing and accidentally left in that bit of code by mistake. Fixed now.

Answer (score 3):

Follow the suggestions of Alan Munn for the first graph.
For the others graphs try this code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \begin{document}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.5]
             \filldraw[yellow] (1,1) rectangle (17,11);
             \path (2,2)--(9,10) node[inner sep=0pt,pos=.2] (a) {};
             \path (16,2)--(9,10) node[inner sep=0pt,pos=.2] (b) {};
             \filldraw[green!60!black] (2,2)--(9,10)--(16,2);
             \filldraw[gray!20] (a)--(9,10)--(b);
             \path[black] (a)--(b) node[pos=.5,above] () {n-th level};
         \end{tikzpicture}
         \hspace{.2cm}
         \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.5]
             \filldraw[yellow] (1,1) rectangle (17,11);
             \path (2,2)--(9,10) node[inner sep=0pt,pos=.2] (a1) {};
             \path (16,2)--(9,10) node[inner sep=0pt,pos=.2] (b1) {};
             \path (2,2)--(16,2) node[inner sep=0pt,pos=.2] (c) {};
             \filldraw[gray!20] (2,2)--(9,10)--(16,2);
             \filldraw[green!60!black] (a1)--(2,2)--(c);
             \draw[black] (a1)--(b1) node[pos=.5,above] () {n-th level};
         \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

The output is:

[image]